# Force links not to break in 2 lines

Tags: php, css

I'm generating links `<a>`with `$_GET [Array]` to show in a box. Per line approx. 5 -10 links. I'm looking for a solution to style those links - to ensure that none to them will show in 2 lines. 
I'm using `{text-align:justify;}` to have the same border distance, but would like to know if there is any way to keep those links from showing in 2 lines.

This is my CSS

```
.box {
width       : 782px;
min-height  : 120px; 
position    : relative;
padding     : 10px 10px 40px 10px; 
border      : 1px solid #D3D3D3;
margin-left : 5px;
text-align  :justify;
}

.link a {
position        :relative;
padding         : 1px 6px;
border-right    : 1px dotted #555;
color           : #555;
text-decoration : none;
font-size       :15px;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that this will work.  I've updated the JSFiddle with more links, and you can take a look to see if that's the display that you're looking for.  The last line isn't justified, but that would be expected.

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7yUB2/)

Comment: @Brian Hoover Thanks for the answer. I might use it wrong or didn't phrase my question clearly but I'm trying it and the result is like in your JSFiddle 1 line with all links in it. What I'm looking for is to generate multi lines but keep just the last link of each line without a break. In case that it doesn't fit in the box, it should show as the 1st link of the following line. But the general view of all links should be still in the style of text-align:justify. How can I make this work?

Comment: @Teo I'm not sure that this is actually possible by using only CSS

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 white-space:nowrap
```

and don't specify width